# Semi-circular shape of jquery mobile slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, slider

Can the shape of horizontal slider in jQuery mobile be changed to semi circular?

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/slider/

I am looking in to the js file but clueless as to how to approach it. I am looking into it so that I can use it in an Android app.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the initialized HTML for that widget:

```
<div role="application" class="ui-slider  ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all">
    <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="33" aria-valuetext="33" title="33" aria-labelledby="slider-0-label" style="left: 33%; ">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
            <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

As you can see it's just a DIV element. So you can assign a different background-image to the DIV to show a circular track but to get the slider to move in a circular fashion will be much harder.

Here's your start:

```
var mousedown = false;
$(document).delegate('.ui-slider-handle', 'mousedown mouseup mousemove', function (event) {
    if (event.type == 'mousedown') {
        mousedown = true;
    } else if (event.type == 'mouseup') {
        mousedown = false;
    } else if (mousedown) {
        var max     = 150,
            percent = (parseInt(this.style.left) / 100);
        this.style.top = (50 - (Math.sin(percent) * max)) + '%';
    }
});​
```

And a Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yRrYL/1/

Comment: yes, i know, but i am just looking for somewhere to start from!

Comment: well..i tried it actually...it makes sense, but still that curvy movement is a difficult task i guess.

Comment: Well the `element.style.left` property gives you the percent of the way across the slider. You now need to come-up with a function that takes in this horizontal position and outputs a vertical position along a curve, that's why I used `Math.sin()` but I didn't take the time to properly set it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery [roundSlider](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin, it supports in mobile devices and touch devices also.

This roundslider having the similar options like the jQuery mobile slider. It support default, min-range and range slider types. Not only the round slider it also supports various [circle shapes](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#various-circle-shapes) such as quarter, half and pie circle shapes.

Please check the demo of your requirement from [**`jsFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/4/).

**Screenshot of the Output:**

[image: jquery round slider - different circle shapes]

For more details please check the [demos](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) and [documentation](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic is when the slider moves, you want the handle to move on the y axis when it moves on the x axis. assuming the area is a square and you have the semi circle background image as the track. you can apply the logic from the x-axis except for the y, the calculation can stay the same as long as the area is a square. 
is that good for a start?